# int in array keeps becoming zero in C

Tags: c, arrays

This is the code piece I am using for part of an assignment (below the rest of this question)

Whenever I enter the int into an array and printf it directly from an array, it gives the correct value. When i try to use that number in a function, it gives a zero.
I used a few printf statements to trace the issue.

```
Enter number of Instruction classes: 
3
Enter the frequency of the machine (MHz) 
200
Enter CPI: 
2
Enter Count: 
3

a : 0
a1 : 2
b : 0
b1 : 3
z: 0
Cycletotal: 0
Instrtotal: 0
```

any ideas on how to fix this issue?

```
   void enter_params() {
   /*declare local vars*/
   int n;
   int i;
   int f;
   int z, a, b;
   /*prompt for number of inst classes*/
   printf("Enter number of Instruction classes: \n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   /*prompt for frequency of the machine*/
   printf("Enter the frequency of the machine (MHz) \n");
   scanf("%d", &f);
   global_n = n;
   global_f = f;
   /*allocate space for cpi and count arrays*/
   cpi = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   count_i = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

   /*for each instruction class: */

   cycle_total = 0;
   instr_total = 0;
   for (i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
   /*prompt for CPI, Class, and INstruction count with prompts*/
      printf("Enter CPI: \n");
      scanf("%d", &cpi[i]);

      printf("Enter Count: \n");
      scanf("%d", &count_i[i]);

      a = cpi[i];
      b = count_i[i];

      printf("\na : " "%i", a);
      printf("\na1 : " "%i", cpi[i]);
      printf("\nb : " "%i", b);
      printf("\nb1 : " "%i", count_i[i]);

      z = cpi[i] * 3;

      cycle_total += z;
      printf("z: " "%i", z);
      printf("Cycletotal: " "%i", cycle_total);
      instr_total += b;
      printf("Instrtotal: " "%i", instr_total);
   }
   return;
}
```

entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
   #define NULL 0

/*declare global vars*/
/*create dynamic array*/
/* Main MUST BE last, C compiles top to bottom, called programs must be at top, calling at bottom */
double *cpi=NULL, *count_i=NULL;
int cycle_total;
int instr_total;
int global_n, global_f;

void print_params()
{
/* for each row, print class# (i+1), CPI[i], count_i[i]*/
   int i;
   int n = global_n;
   int j = 1;
   printf("------------------------- \n");
   printf("|Class" "\t" "|CPI" "\t" "|Count" "\t" "| \n");
   printf("------------------------- \n");
   for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
   {
      printf("|" "%i", j);
      printf("\t" "|" "%i", cpi[i]);
      printf("\t" "|" "%i", count_i[i]);
      printf("\t" "| \n");
      printf("------------------------- \n");
      j++;
   }
   return;
}

float calculate_average_cpi()
{
   float avg_cpi,calc; /*typecast calculation piece as float, not the final number */

   printf("Cycletotal" "%i", cycle_total);
   printf("InstrTotal" "%i", instr_total);

   avg_cpi = (float)cycle_total / (float)instr_total;
   return avg_cpi;
}

float calculate_cpu_time()
{
   float cpu_time;
   cpu_time = (float)cycle_total / (float)global_f;
   return cpu_time;
}

float calculate_mips(float cpu_time)
{
   float mips;
   mips = (float)instr_total / cpu_time;
   return mips;
}

/*
CPI average is:
Σ(N, i=1) CPI[i]*Ii / Σ(N, i=1) Ii

CPU TIme is:
Σ(N, i=1) CPI[i]*Ii / freq

MIPS is:
Σ(N, i=1) Ii / CPU Time
*/
/* /t is an indent */

void print_perf()
{
/*declare local vars*/
   float avg_cpi = calculate_average_cpi();
   float cpu_time = calculate_cpu_time();
   float mips;
   mips = calculate_mips(cpu_time);

   printf("------------------------- \n");
   printf("|Performance" "\t" "|Value" "\t" "|" "\n");
   printf("------------------------- \n|Average CPI" "\t" "|" "%.2f", avg_cpi);
   printf("\t" "|" "\n------------------------- \n" "|CPU Time (ms)" "\t" "|" "%.2f", cpu_time);
   printf("\t" "|" "\n------------------------- \n" "|MIPS" "\t" "\t" "|" "%.2f", mips);
   printf("\t" "|" "\n------------------------- \n");


   /*print table with those values*/
}



void enter_params() {
   /*declare local vars*/
   int n;
   int i;
   int f;
   int z, a, b;
   /*prompt for number of inst classes*/
   printf("Enter number of Instruction classes: \n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   /*prompt for frequency of the machine*/
   printf("Enter the frequency of the machine (MHz) \n");
   scanf("%d", &f);
   global_n = n;
   global_f = f;
   /*allocate space for cpi and count arrays*/
   cpi = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   count_i = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

   /*for each instruction class: */

   cycle_total = 0;
   instr_total = 0;
   for (i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
   /*prompt for CPI, Class, and INstruction count with prompts*/
      printf("Enter CPI: \n");
      scanf("%d", &cpi[i]);

      printf("Enter Count: \n");
      scanf("%d", &count_i[i]);

      a = cpi[i];
      b = count_i[i];

      printf("\na : " "%i", a);
      printf("\na1 : " "%i", cpi[i]);
      printf("\nb : " "%i", b);
      printf("\nb1 : " "%i", count_i[i]);

      z = cpi[i] * 3;

      cycle_total += z;
      printf("z: " "%i", z);
      printf("Cycletotal: " "%i", cycle_total);
      instr_total += b;
      printf("Instrtotal: " "%i", instr_total);
   }
   return;
}

void quit_program()
{
   if (cpi!=NULL) free(cpi);
   if (count_i!=NULL) free(count_i);
   return;
}


int main() 
{
   int choice = 0;
   printf("Performance Assessment: \n");
   printf("1) Enter Parameters \n");
   printf("2) Print Table of Parameters \n");
   printf("3) Print Table of Performance \n");
   printf("4) Quit \n");
   scanf("%d", &choice);
   while (choice != 4)
   {
      if (choice == 1)
      {
         enter_params();
      }
      if (choice == 2)
      {
         print_params();
      }
      if (choice == 3)
      {
         print_perf();
      }
      printf("Performance Assessment: \n");
      printf("1) Enter Parameters \n");
      printf("2) Print Table of Parameters \n");
      printf("3) Print Table of Performance \n");
      printf("4) Quit \n");
      scanf("%d", &choice);
   }
   quit_program();
}
```

Comment: Where did you try and use it in a function?

Comment: updated my post with the full code. Its supposed to be a simple assignment to calculate computer performance.

Comment: Why do you declare cpi and count_i as pointer to double, but assign them a pointer to integer?

Comment: I have no idea but that was the problem, making them ints fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @someonewhodied Does the rpgram consists from several modules and cpi count_i are defined in each modulw?

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then use a debugger (`gdb`), and put some watchpoints (command `watch` of `gdb`) to understand how is a variable changing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: the problem in the code are in lines `a = cpi[i]; b = count_i[i];`.
Here `cpi` & `cpi_i` are `double` which means they occupy 8bytes(compiler dependent); whereas `a` & `b` are `integer`s which are of size 4 bytes (compiler dependent).
So the compiler by default makes `cpi` & `count_i` pointers as `integer` pointers.
Now if you see the array as `double array cpi = {02 xx yy zz}` of size 4 but the same array when addressed as `int array cpi = { 0 2 x x y y z z}` of size 8. hence `cpi[0] = 0; cpi[1] = 2;`

Solution: either declare `cpi` & `count_i` as integer pointers (highly recommended) or

use as:

```
a = int((double) cpi[i]); //Not so recomended
```

Again careful while assigning an int to cpi: `cpi[i] = (double) a;`